# Most efficient way to pass Entity information to a jquery dialog in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I have this ASP.NET MVC 3 Page where I'm looping a collection of objects in the Model, and basically I will have a button next to each entity information/display to allow the user to edit that entity in a jQuery UI dialog.

What I'm stuck with is finding the best way to pass the information of the entity to the jquery dialog.

I'm thinking of either using many data-x attributes, one for each property of the object, or just storing the entity JSON representation in a single data-x attribute.

What would be the best approach to pass the information and assign it in the jQuery UI dialog? If someone has any samples that'd be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you may consider doing instead is to set up a controller that is responsible for issuing services as strings of JSON, and then call that service in your button click event (that launches the jQuery dialog).  To do this, you will need the help of a JSON serializer like [jsonfx](https://github.com/jsonfx/jsonfx) (my personal favorite) which you can download in VS as a nuget package.

For example, if you were calling up a single entity:

```
public class ServiceController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult GetFoo(FormCollection fc)
        {
            var json = MyFooGetter(fc["fooId"]); //Id of the object
            var writer = new JsonWriter();
            return Content(writer.Write(json), "application/json");
        }
}
```

On the client side, you request this service like this:

```
$.post("/service/GetFoo", {fooId: "1"}, function (response) {
        //Do stuff with your response object which is a traversable JSON version of your entity(ies).
        //Example:
        var h1 = $("<h1>");
        h1.html(response.title);
        $("document").append(h1);
    });
```

Another example for an entity collection:

```
public class ServiceController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult GetFooCollection()
        {
            var json = MyFooCollectionGetter(); 
            var writer = new JsonWriter();
            return Content(writer.Write(json), "application/json");
       }
}
```

On the client side, you request this service like this:

```
$.post("/service/GetFooCollection", function (response) {
        //Do stuff with your response object which is a traversable JSON version of your entity(ies).
        //Example:
       $.each(response,function(i){
          alert(response[i].title);
       });
    });
```

Good luck!

Comment: tell me you don't actually use the ContentResult type for json.  Use JsonResult, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470587(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: @nathangonzalez--They accomplish the same thing.  If you disagree, then please enlighten the rest of us.  Or, better yet, put the effort into an answer that benefits the OP as well as the rest of the community.

Comment: thanks Matthew. The only downside that I see to that approach is that I'd have to make an extra request to the server in order to get information that I'm already looping and can embed in the page before hand.

Comment: No problem.  In the context of my suggestion, you wouldn't "embed" the information into your view (using Razor I assume).  Instead, you would load the base structure for your page (a much lighter thing to do) and then *request* a lightweight JSON package to get your data.  If you must support browsers without JS, however, it is a problem.

Comment: @nathangonzalez--And to correct myself a bit, they don't do the same thing.  In my scenario, I have already serialized the object into a string of JSON and that's all I need to return.  Your suggestion is that I serialize it again which makes no sense (at least to me).

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt yep, I'm using Razor. well, thing is I do have to display the complete entity information on the view anyways, that's why I just want to put a json representation of my entity in a data-whatever attribute. Do you know how to do this? I've tried a couple of ways but haven't succeeded yet.

Comment: I can't say that I understand what you mean, but I have shown you how to serialize an entity into JSON.  You can use that part of my code example to stick a string of JSON into your `data-x` attribute if that works best for you (to be clear though, I don't recommend this approach--far too inefficient).

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt, why would anything return a json string?  and to get the string you've done your own serialization, which is entirely unnecessary.  its not that what you have written won't do the job, its that what you have written is suboptimal, more verbose then necessary, and probably would violate dry if i saw the rest of the made up implementation.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt I really don't see how going back to the server to get information you already have when you're creating the view is more efficient than having a few more bytes of html markup by having a few json properties of your entity to use when launching the dialog.

Comment: and about returning a json string, i mean i want to put a json string in the data-information attribute, so that when the button is clicked, i can parse that json string and assign the values of the entity to the dialog fields.

Comment: @nathangonzalez--'Why would anything return a json string?': A great question for the thousands of apps and APIs out there that do just that.  Look up Facebook's Open Graph API for example (it's pretty well documented).  As for your assessment of my 'made up implementation', you may consider that yours is not the only way to do things.  There are good reasons that .NET libraries for JSON have been created such as jsonfx and Json.Net--they offer more facilities than just serialization and are often just more flexible than using just a JSON result.  Again, why not offer your own, better answer?

Comment: @GR7--I don't think you understand what I was suggesting, but you wouldn't be going back to the server to get info you already have.  You would instead be asking your middle tier to only render the shell of what you need (<input type='button' class='SelectorForClickHandler' data-id='IdOfYourObject' value='Click here to edit in a jQuery modal' />)  Then you send that only to the client.  When the client clicks a particular button, THEN you go get the data for that object.  This is offloading work from your web server to the client and only requesting the data that the client actually needs.

Comment: And by "offloading work from the web server to the client" I mean that you are placing the business of creating DOM elements or a form on the client (where it belongs) and not in Razor (which is processed on the server).

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt I did understand what you were saying, which was just setting the ID of the object that would be edited on the popup, and only if clicked, then pass the id to the popup and have the popup issue a second http request (the first one was the screen loading one) to get the information it needs.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt While that approach would certainly be ideal for a page with many records or very heavy objects, my page is displaying a list of paintings of a given gallery, of which the painting class only has about 4 or 5 editable properties, and the painting list wouldn't go above 30. I am aware that i'm trading rendering data attributes that might not be load at all, by pursing a more faster/seamless popup/edit load which would not need a call to the server, since all the data that would be edited would already be passed as values to the popup.

thanks for your answer though.